# System of 2 linear q-difference equations with singular matrix

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra

I would like to solve the following algebraic linear system of q-difference functional equations:

\begin{cases}
a_{11}\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)+a_{12}\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)=f\left(qx\right)\\
\\
a_{21}\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)+a_{22}\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)=g\left(qx\right)
\end{cases}

where all the functions are $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
In more detail, the functions $a_{ij}\left(x\right)$ are known (moreover they are analytic and bounded between $0$ and $1$), and the purpose is to determine $f\left(x\right)$ and $g\left(x\right)$.
The parameter $q$ is smaller than $1$.
If we define:

\begin{equation}
A\left(x\right)\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11}\left(x\right) & a_{12}\left(x\right)\\
a_{21}\left(x\right) & a_{22}\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

we have $\det A\left(x\right)\neq0\;\forall x\neq0$ and $\det\left(I-A\left(0\right)\right)\neq0$ (this is due to the special form of the functions $a_{ij}\left(x\right)$ I'm using).
From numerical analysis I know that this system has also non-zero solutions.

**MY APPROACH**

I've tried to solve this problem using the methods developed for q-difference equations (see for example [this link](http://www.uclouvain.be/cps/ucl/doc/math/documents/RAPSEM354.pdf)).
From the system of equations we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)\\
g\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]=A^{-1}\left(x\right)\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(qx\right)\\
g\left(qx\right)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

therefore if we iterate $n$-times we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)\\
g\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]=\left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}A^{-1}\left(q^{i}x\right)\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(q^{n}x\right)\\
g\left(q^{n}x\right)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

where:

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}A^{-1}\left(q^{i}x\right)=A^{-1}\left(x\right)A^{-1}\left(qx\right)\cdots A^{-1}\left(q^{n-1}x\right)
\end{equation}

Thefore in the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$, since $q<1$, we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)\\
g\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]=\left[\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}A^{-1}\left(q^{i}x\right)\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(0\right)\\
g\left(0\right)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

Now, for $x=0$, the system of equations becomes:

\begin{cases}
a_{11}\left(0\right)f\left(0\right)+a_{12}\left(0\right)g\left(0\right)=f\left(0\right)\\
\\
a_{21}\left(0\right)f\left(0\right)+a_{22}\left(0\right)g\left(0\right)=g\left(0\right)
\end{cases}

therefore we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(0\right)\\
g\left(0\right)
\end{array}\right]=\left[I-A\left(0\right)\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

since $\det\left(I-A\left(0\right)\right)\neq0$ by hypothesis.
Clearly the matrix $\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}A^{-1}\left(q^{i}x\right)$ is singular, since $\det A\left(0\right)=0$ by hypothesis. Therefore we have obtained the indeterminate solution $\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)\\
g\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]=\infty\cdot0$, which is not good. Since this method doesn't work, do you know how this system can be solved? Maybe there is an alternative approach. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: simplification of the problem**

In order to simplify further the description of this problem, below I write its 1D equivalent case:

\begin{equation}
a\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)=f\left(qx\right)
\end{equation}

where $a\left(x\right)$ is known and such that $a\left(0\right)=0$. So for example we can consider the functional equation $xf\left(x\right)=f\left(qx\right)$. How can I calculate $f\left(x\right)$, given that $f\left(x\right)=0$ for $x\leq0$?

Comment: Maybe the "matrix" $\prod_{i=0}^\infty A^{-1}(q^i x)$ is not a matrix... (does the infinite product converges?). Without specifics about the $a_{ij}$ the question seems difficult to answer. In particular it is not clear to me why $\det A(0)=0$ and $\det (I-A(0))\neq 0$ should hold.

Comment: The functions $a_{ij}\left(x\right)$ are analytic and bounded between 0 and 1 (I'll add these details in the original post), while $\det\left(I-A\left(0\right)\right)\neq0$ is what I obtain numerically for the special functions $a_{ij}\left(x\right)$ I'm using. As you said, the infinite product does diverge, so probably this is not the right approach to follow.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ assumed to be continuous, too? You take the limit for $n\to\infty$ assuming that they are...

Comment: @ Federico: Well, actually they aren't. For this reason I haven't tried any Taylor expansion approach. The discontinuity is in $x=0$.

Comment: There is some litterrature about q-Gevrey resumation of divergent formal power series solution to q-difference equations, which seems to be your case. This study is relatively recent, check papers by Ramis, Sauloy, Zhang etc.

Comment: ... But you'll have to wander in the complex line to understand things like Stokes phenomena, even if you start from real functions.

Comment: @ Loïc: ok thanks for the info, I'll read their papers carefully!

Comment: @user2983638 I'm confused -- then how can you claim that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q^nx) = f(0)$?

Comment: @ Federico: you are right, I didn't think about that. However I'm not saying that the method I have used is right. I would like to find an alternative method, since the one shown above doesn't work.

Comment: In general you begin by looking at formal power series solutions, then study convergence. What you typically obtain are q-sumable series, admitting a q-Gevrey asymptotic expansion near $x=0$, guaranteeing continuity of "genuine" solutions. If you don't have this property then the problem is an order of magnitude more difficult...

Comment: @ Loïc: actually the solutions are not continuous in $x=0$. For the special functions $a_{ij}\left(x\right)$ I'm using, the (numerical) solution is equal to zero for $x\leq0$ and positive for $x>0$.

Comment: @user2983638: how do you compute the numerical solutions?

Comment: Hello, the 1D case has been solved [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154194/a-linear-algebraic-q-difference-equation), so I think this method can be applied also to our 2D case!